# Write correctly class name inside onclick of HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, syntax

I have a class named validate['required'] and I need to put it inside

```
onclick="something();document.getElementById('something').setAttribute('class',here);"
```

the problem is that I get a syntax error : missing ) after argument list.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Does `something()` contain anything that produces an error? Did you change `here`?

Comment: the problem is that if I replace here by 'validate['required']' I get the error above and if I put 'validate[required' I get no error but the class it not called.

Comment: @pimvdb No something() works ok and yes I replace here by my class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your comments I *guess* you are doing:

```
onclick="something();document.getElementById('something').setAttribute('class','vaildate['required']');"
```

The string between `onclick="..."` is parsed by the JavaScript interpreter of the browser.

Of the JavaScript code, this fails:

```
'vaildate['required']'
```

because the JavaScript interpreter will think everything between `'` and `'` will be your class name, so in your case:

```
vaildate[
```

Then the interpreter also reads `required']'` which it does not know how to handle, thus producing an error.

To literally use the `'` character without the browser using it as the end, you can escape it by prepending `\`:

```
'vaildate[\'required\']'
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
onclick="something();document.getElementById('something').setAttribute('class','validate[\'required\']');"
```